# Можно ли гуглить в Яндексе?

Tags: словообразование

Если меня просят погуглить какую-то информацию, а я при этом пользуюсь Яндексом или там.. Нигмой. Можно ли сказать, что я все равно погуглил? Если я выдаю найденную в другом поисковике инфу и говорю - "Вот нагуглил", я обманываю?

Ведь слова "яндексить" нет.

Answer (score 4):

Могу предложить универсальную русскую форму для всех видов поисковиков : "нашел в ..."

Answer (score 3):

> > Можно ли сказать, что я все равно погуглил?

Если уж вы говорите **инфа**, то можете ее и гуглить, и яндексить, и даже рамблерить.

Comment: Ок, я исправил на "информацию". Что можно теперь? :)

Comment: Теперь-то как раз и нельзя. Только гуглить. Скорее исправляйте обратно. )))

Comment: Ну, меня слова типа "инфа" не смущают. Я не страдаю снобизмом такого рода и могу использовать интернет-сленг при общении в интернете.

Comment: Тогда и вопроса нет. Гуглить, яндексить -- что угодно.

Comment: Это называется - сказать нечего, хочется пофлцуди

Comment: С вас пример беру. Хотите поговорить серьезно – задавайте вопросы поумнее.

Comment: "С вас пример беру" - забавно, когда человек прилюдно признает себя поцем. :))

Answer (score 1):

Для англоязычного интернета рекомендация Википедии вполне уместна, а для нас Гугл и Яндекс - два конкурента, битва между которыми [в самом разгаре](http://www.vedomosti.ru/newspaper/articles/2015/02/10/yandeks-teryaet-mobilnost). Поэтому "гуглить на Яндексе" звучит как провокация.

Слоган Яндекса: "Найдётся всё". Поэтому на Яндексе - находим, а на Гугле можно и "погуглить" ;)

Заметил, что намерение "пойду погуглю" звучит неконкретно: пойду искать с помощью Гугла, Яндекса, Фейсбука... А вот если уже нашёл и говорю "погуглил", то звучит, будто нашёл именно Гуглом.

**Обновление**

Попробую ещё раз. Значение слова "гуглить" ещё не устоялось, и не все готовы его принять. [Посмотрим карту](http://coolfaq.ru/img/map_poisk.jpg).

Если человек найдёт в Яндексе и скажет "Вот нагуглил", то собеседник на серой территории поймёт правильно. На территориях другого цвета - запутается, а на жёлтой - засмеётся или обидится. Советы Википедии верны только для того, кто готов им последовать, и только тогда, когда он общается с себе подобным. Но понимать контекст разговора и осознанно добиваться от собеседника нужной реакции - это всегда правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно данным Викисловаря и Википедии, слово гуглить может быть использовано, когда подразумевается поиск в интернете вообще.

Answer (score 0):

"Яндексить" ничем не хуже "гуглить". Ни то, ни другое не входит в число нормативно кодифицированных, а потому правила употребления никем не могут быть установлены. Я за то, что "гуглить" может использоваться в широком смысле (как и "гугл" - вообще "поисковик", как нарицательное), но если для вас важно подчеркнуть, что поиск осуществлялся именно Яндексом, то "яндексить" вполне приемлемо.

Comment: "Яндексить" со всей очевидностью хуже.

Comment: А мне вот "со всей очевидностью" не нравится ваш аргумент. Что теперь? Всеми очевидностями мерится будем?

Comment: Фу... Простите, дальнейшей общение с Вами не представляет для меня никакого интереса.